# Keras/Python equivalent of Matlab's genFunction in nn toolbox

Tags: python, matlab, neural-network, keras

I have coded a Neural Network with 3 hidden layers (using the Keras module in Python). Code for the net is below:

```
# Create the model
np.random.seed(1)   # Just for reproducibility of results

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(input_dim=x.shape[1],
                output_dim=50,
                init='uniform',
                activation='tanh'))

model.add(Dense(input_dim=50,
                output_dim=50,
                init='uniform',
                activation='tanh'))

model.add(Dense(input_dim=50,
                output_dim=10,
                init='uniform',
                activation='tanh'))

model.add(Dense(input_dim=10,
                output_dim=1,
                init='uniform',
                activation='linear'))

optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-08)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer)

history = model.fit(x,y,nb_epoch=2000,batch_size=20,verbose=1,validation_split=0.1)
```

I have trained the Neural Network and have the weights matrix.

But, there is a software where I want to use this function learnt by the Neural Network and that software does not have support for neural networks. So, I directly have to give this equation to that software. Basically, I want to express this neural network as a function of only the input features (say, x1, x2, x3, ..., xd).

As the no. of hidden layers increases, this task becomes more tedious to do manually. From a few searches, I came to know that the genFunction() in the **nn toolboox of MATLAB** does exactly this. But sadly, I can't use MATLAB here.

I want to know if there is a function in Keras (or in Python in general) that does this, i.e, can it give me the function equation directly, or maybe a code snippet that takes in x1,x2,...,xd as input and returns the output value?

Comment: In what programming language or framework do you want to use this function?